# securing pages in a folder with user roles?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5, sqlmembershipprovider

I am managing different roles pages in different folders in my application rote. Admin folder has all pages of admin. User has all pages of loged in user.

Please advice what way I should adopt to check that user is valid and have correct permissions ?

*I was thinking I should user sessioon variables, as a user logs in I keep its Id and user type in session. Can there be some more elegent and less coding required way ?*

The page where user signs in is a detail page with almost 25 fields and it has ajax validations, and othe client and server side validations.

I dont know much about membership providers by asp.net and never used these , Kindly if you advice something reffer me some link or keyword to look further.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can manage such configuration easily in the web.config. Simply add in a `configuration` section of `web.config`.

```
<location path="Admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>               
        <allow roles="Administrator"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

`<deny users="?"/>` mean's unauthenticated user will not be able to access the `Admin` Folder

An example with another Folder, you want to allow, that has `Manager Role`:

```
<location path="ManagerFolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>               
        <allow roles="Manager"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Akhtar  thanks, Please guide how to do it in custom code snario. For registration I am using custom code, can I use with my custom code that save a user in db table ? I have roles column in my db with values but after these configurations how I will manage ? Should I keep my user type in session variable ? How I can use you guidance with my snario. thanks

Comment: You can use like to check the uesr, if lies in particular role. if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("RoleName"))

Comment: @Mhuammad Akhtar, but will I need to put user type in session ?

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting what benefit it will bring then doing it by custom code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links

[Implementing Role-Based Security with ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111727/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121901-1.shtml)

[Implementing Role-Based Security with ASP.NET, Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20190829043329/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121901-1.2.shtml)

[Role-based Security with Forms Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/formsroleauth.aspx)

Hope these will help you get started